# CSS Layout Help - Stretch div to bottom of page

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create a layout with a 'header' area which contains a logo and some links, and then a content area which needs to extend to the bottom of the page. This is where I'm getting stuck.

I've surrounded the header and content with a container div which has a height of 100%, this works fine. But I can't then get the content div to stretch to the bottom of the container div as giving it a minimum height of 100% appears to take the height from the page body, so I end up with a scroll bar due to the space taken up at the top of the page by the header.

Here's a wireframe which hopefully makes what I'm trying to achieve a bit clearer...

[image: Mockup]

Here is a quick CSS example, this works, apart from there always being a scrollbar at which appears to be the height of the header area...

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#header {
    padding-top: 26px;
}
#logo {
    width: 194px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#content {
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: just tested my answer on this one, works fine as long as your header has a fixed height.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just updated my example, added a fixed height to my header and set the 'top' value for the content to be the height of the header and margins. However I'm still seeing a scroll bar.

Comment: remove the min-height of the content div

Comment: Works great, until the contents of the the content div exceed the height of the page, then the div moves from the bottom of the page.

Comment: Hmm, what do you want to happen when the content exceeds the page? A scrollbar? If you set overflow:auto to the content div it will give a scrollbar on the div only (not on the entire page).

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/CZayc/

this works by wrapping the header and body in a div to push footer down

index.html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        main<br/>main<br/>main<br/>main<br/>main<br/>main<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

style.css

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header {
    border-top:20px solid #fff;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; width: 90%; margin: auto; }
#wrap { min-height: 100%;background-color:gray;}
#main {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 53px; /* must be same height as the footer */
    background-color: red;
    height: 90%
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -53px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    border-bottom:20px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: This is just a link, not an answer.  Could you bring in some of the information from the link?

Answer (score 2):

Make the container div position:relative and the content div position:absolute. Then give the content div top:<header height> and bottom:0

Not in a position to test this right now, but I think something like this should work.

Comment: alternately, you could use javascript to fix this after loading, but that's not my preferred choice (altough I had to resort to this method in one of my websites)

Comment: This should work in IE7+. See my [example 100% height layout](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/q9yL6/).

Answer (score 0):

limitations:
header height should be static, with an absolute height.

content height is dynamic.

CSS code:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
#header {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:20;
    height: 7em;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#content {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 7em;
    min-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

content stretch all the way to the bottom, even when text is short.

when content's text is longer than our window height - we get the auto scroll

Example:
  http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/p3B4s/3/