# Stretch DIV to Bottom & Remove Scrollbar

Tags: css

I have a design where there is a header set at `absolute` position with a height of `379px`. My content is also set at `absolute` position with `top:232px` as well. I am successfully getting the content div to stretch to the bottom of the page, however, because of the extra `232px` even if the content does not pass the height of the window a vertical scroll bar is added.

I've looked around and have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657122/css-layout-help-stretch-div-to-bottom-of-page) topic posted which pretty much is the issue I'm having. Unfortunately, none of the solutions posted on that page have solved my problem. Here is my CSS code:

```
 #wrapper   { position:absolute; top:0; left:50%; width:1000px; height:100%; margin-left:-500px; }
 #header    { z-index:1; position:absolute; top:0px; background:url(../images/layout/backdrop.png) no-repeat; width:1000px; height:379px; }
 #container {
      position:relative;
      top:232px;
      bottom:0;
      background-color:#d7d7d7;
      width:739px;
      height:100%;
      min-height:100%;
      margin-left:175px;
      border:1px solid #000;
      border-bottom:0;
      border-top-right-radius:20px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright:20px;
}
```

And the HTML Code:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="container">

      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: try to use `height:auto; overflow:hidden;` in `#wrapper an #container`

Comment: adding it to `#content` did not produce any results, however, adding `overflow:hidden` to `#wrapper` did take the scrollbar away. The only problem is, when the content passes max-height it will not scroll... :o

Comment: **Update**: By using `min-height:-moz-calc()` in `#container` I was able to achieve the results I wanted but this method is not very cross-browser functional...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that nobody has been able to answer this, i'll post my solution to the problem.

Although I didn't exactly achieve it the way I wanted to which was to use strictly CSS, I still got it to stretch to the bottom using javascript with jQuery's library.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    /*
        Method calculates container height and stretches to bottom of page
        if content does not fill entire space.
    */
    function setHeight() {
        // Get css values needed to compute height.
        var topAttr = parseInt($('#container').css('top'), 10); // convert value to int...
        var winHeight = $(window).height(); // get user's browser height...
        var conHeight = $('#container').height(); // get container height...

        // If the size of the container is less than the size of the user's window... resize.
        if(conHeight < winHeight) {
            var newHeight = (winHeight - topAttr) - 1; // calculate the new height....
            $('#container').height(newHeight); // apply the height value to the container.
        }
    }

    // Run as soon as page loads...
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setHeight();
    });
// ]]>
```

I then, added a `noscript` block at the bottom of the text that appears in a red box asking the user to enable javascrpt...

```
<!-- DISPLAY IF USER HAS JAVA DISABLED -->
<noscript><div class="nojava">
    It has been detected that you have disabled javascript from running. Please consider enabling javascript in that it will improve this website's functionality substantially.
</div></noscript>
<!-- DISPLAY IF USER HAS JAVA DISABLED -->
```

I'm sure there is someone out there that can

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Layout Help - Stretch div to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657122/css-layout-help-stretch-div-to-bottom-of-page)

http://jsfiddle.net/CZayc/