# css stretch div to bottom

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xHTML/CSS: How to make inner div get 100% width minus another div width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198116/xhtml-css-how-to-make-inner-div-get-100-width-minus-another-div-width)

I would like to stretch the bottom div to the bottom of the page...

If possible with css. If css is not possible, javascript is also ok.
Preferrably a solution which works in IE as well.

UPDATE:
I worked it out in javascript myself (based on the answer of another so question), but css to get the same result would be better of course...

Comment: There are so many similar question about this you can see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657122/css-layout-help-stretch-div-to-bottom-of-page  || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820801/stretch-div-to-bottom-remove-scrollbar  ||

Comment: similar, but not the same. I saw a number of questions here indeed, but none of them apply to my case.

Comment: okay so what is your bottom div? what exactly you want?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LK44Y/1/

Comment: @Pankaj: no, the blue bar should stay at the (absolute) bottom of the window. The 'bottomContainer' should stretch to the blue bar.

Comment: @Pankaj: see the updated version at http://www.druppeltje.be/site/nieuws/ for an example.

Comment: Okay got it according to me there is no way of getting this without putting height or content in this section, if your remove position fix from that blue bar this will work the way you want to and when you'll put the content on this it will increase

Answer (score 0):

If i understand clearly you want an Sticky Footer technique check this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: This does not work for me. I cannot use a wrapper class that wraps the entire page, because part of my page has a width of 100%.