# CSS: Stretch content div to footer div and align horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to take a div that sits underneath a menu, stretch it until it reaches the footer (in case there's not enough content), and center it. I can stretch it using absolute positioning, but it will not center; and I can center it, but it won't stretch. The code looks something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    background: #111;
    width: 500px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: auto;
}

#content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #666;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #111;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's an image I created in Inkscape as an example: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=46baeba

I can find answers on how to stretch the content div to the bottom, but that's it. I don't want to use JavaScript/JQuery unless I absolutely need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on doing things the way you are (with the footer set to `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`) you can do:

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; // or whatever height you want
}
#content {
    width: 500px;
    background: #666;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px; // same height as header
    bottom: 50px; // same height as footer
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2y9Y/

But I think for what you're trying to achieve, setting absolute positioning is probably a bad idea. Are you sure your content will never be taller than 100% of the user's browser height? Why not simply set a `min-height` on the content? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g2y9Y/1/

Comment: I'm not set in using anything but CSS3. And I know my content will likely fill the screen, but in the rare instance that it doesn't, I want to be prepared. As for your suggestion, it works provided I don't scroll down on pages that have more content.

Comment: Also, if I absolutely need to, I don't mind using JavaScript/JQuery. I just prefer a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZayc/)** . I found it here - [CSS Layout Help - Stretch div to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657122/css-layout-help-stretch-div-to-bottom-of-page)

```
#wrap { min-height: 100%;background-color:gray;}
#main {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 53px; /* must be same height as the footer */
    background-color: red;
    height: 90%
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -53px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    border-bottom:20px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:blue;
}
```